# Is it faster to run or dodge roll?

Tags: pokemon-legends-arceus

I'm having a tough time trying to determine which form of movement is faster in the game since I can't reliably hit the dodge-roll button exactly when it is off of cooldown. As you see in many speedruns, dodge-rolling is often quicker/better at covering distances. Is this also the case in Arceus?

Comment: Are you asking about the travel inside Jubilife Village? Of course it’s faster to use a ride Pokémon outside of the village, so I assume so?

Comment: :O I'm not that far into the game yet! I guess then yes, it would apply to the village then. Although I can't see the movement to be different inside the village than the open world (non-riding).

Comment: The difference would come from non flat terrain - one or the other may be faster or slower at hills or small bumps.  But I think the village is the more relevant in terms of what amount of total time you spend running (and not riding).

Comment: Ahhh. The good ol “jumping is the faster form of waking” trope

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I did the empirical way, from the stash to the trading post, and it takes:

- ~13.5s running
- ~16s dodge-rolling

But, considering that your character have a sort of stamina that you consume while running, you can dodge-roll while recovering. Mixing both techniques I got **~13s**!

So it appears to be faster to run until you get tired, then dodge-roll a couple of times in order to recover and then run again.

Comment: Didn't notice you'd made this edit before I submitted mine - glad we agree here! So odd that the rolling resets the stamina meter.

Comment: @Joe that explains why you posted a different answer that was totally supporting mine :) better safe than sorry, empirical results may differ so good to know!

Answer (score 13):

From my own empirical testing dodge rolling neither is slower nor faster than running so long as you are running in between.  A run from the item store by the gate to the trading post for me is just under 13,5s, and a run of the same distance with five dodge rolls but running in between is also about 13.5s.

One thing to note is that dodge rolls seem to reset your run stamina - I can start running, dodge roll periodically, and never have to reset the run even doing much more than one loop; while just running I lose stamina about halfway to the trading post.

As such, the fastest option is to run with a dodge roll interspersed often enough to not lose stamina. I can do the storage to trading post consistently in 12.5s that way, with two or three dodge rolls.